# How to get the id from the first li in a ul list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use Javascript and Jquery to get the id value of a ul list from an array I generate from the list the arrays value is lis but I cant get the id value out of that I have tried to use .innerHTML but that outputs the whole thing and not just the id? .value outputs nothing and .id also outputs nothing. What should I do to get the id from the array lis.
the code is below

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
   $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable" class="dummy" >
  <li class="ui-state-default" value="aa" ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" id="1a" ></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" id="2b" ></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" id="3c" ></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" id="4d" ></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" id="5e" ></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" id="6f" ></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s" id="7g" ></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
 <script>
var theObject = document.getElementById("sortable");
var lis = theObject.children;
alert(lis[0].innerHTML.value);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML and JS code.

Comment: sorry I forgot the code.

Comment: Actually, your `<li>` elements don't have IDs. The `<span>` elements that they contain do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this list

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

You could use this code to get the ids of all `<li>`:

```
map=Function.prototype.call.bind([].map)
list=document.querySelectorAll("li");
ids=(map(list, function(x){return x.id;}))
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N36Z3/) to play with. Look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) Documentation for `Array.map()`.

Comment: it ok enhzflep answered my question

Answer (score 0):

```
var ulElement = document.getElementById('sortable');
var liElements = ulElement.getElementsByTagName('li');

var spanElements = liElements[0].getElementsByTagName('span');
var idOfInterest = spanElements[0].id;
```

This code will set the idOfInterest to '1a'